# Is there any full node software for bitcoin with serious wallet functionality?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet

I'm looking for a bitcoin software with a full-featured wallet functionality and running a full node, but I cannot find any.

Bitcoin Core does run a full node and the network capabilities are great, but the wallet functionality is very limited, it does not support BIP39 mnemonic (so there is no easy way to store the private key on paper for security), the addresses are stored on disk without encryption (it does encrypt private keys, but only that). So any backup have all this data.

On the other hand, electrum wallet seems to support everything, but it connects to electrum nodes only (it does not connect to the bitcoin network) and it send public address there to query for transactions.

Is there any alternative I'm missing? I thing that any sofware that make the wallet side of the equation while connecting to the full node I'm already running should work, but could not find any thin client wallet for bitcoin.

Comment: re: *"but the wallet functionality is very limited, it does not support BIP39 mnemonic"* -- I wouldn't call the Bitcoin-core wallet limited at all! It doesn't support BIP 39, so I understand your frustration there, but otherwise it has extremely broad transactional capability. I don't know of a wallet with more fine-grained control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect your Electrum wallet to your own Electrum server to preserve privacy. There are different Electrum server implementations:

- [Electrum Personal Server](https://github.com/chris-belcher/electrum-personal-server)

  > Electrum Personal Server aims to make using Electrum bitcoin wallet more secure and more private. It makes it easy to connect your Electrum wallet to your own full node.
- [ElectrumX - Reimplementation of electrum-server](https://github.com/kyuupichan/electrumx)

  > A reimplementation of Electrum-Server for a future with bigger blocks.
- [electrs - Electrum Server in Rust](https://github.com/romanz/electrs)

  > The motivation behind this project is to enable a user to run his own Electrum server, with required hardware resources not much beyond those of a full node.

Comment: This seems like what I'm looking for, but it seems to require adding an extra layer of complexity. So not only a wallet layer (electrum), also an electrum-server layer and finally the P2P network layer (bitcoin-core). Anyway it is the better option by now.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in the work being done on [HWI (hardware wallet interface)](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/HWI). See also: [using HWI with bitcoin-core](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/HWI/blob/master/docs/bitcoin-core-usage.md).

This software is still in development, so use at your own risk, but it may help accomplish the goal of being able to use bitcoin-core as a full node to validate transactions related to your wallet, while having an efficient backup method, and without needing to keep your private keys on an internet-exposed machine.

Comment: It is really interesting, but I don't have a hardware wallet (yet).

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in bcoin. It’s a full node implementation written for nodejs. Purse.io uses it for its backend and we do over $1,000,000/month in bitcoin transactions.

The bcoin wallet is bip44 based and scales very well to hundreds of thousands of accounts and addresses. It can be run as a plug-in or on a separate server. We have a robust multi signature application that supports hardware signing on devices like Ledger and Trezor.

https://GitHub.com/bcoin-org/bcoin

We’re on slack if you have any more questions about it. Docs and guides: https://bcoin.io